# Authenticate user logged on different subdomain

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I want to use [laravel/passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) auth2 authentication in **master** service: user login into **master.example.com** and then he click on "go to module One" button. Then he is redirected to **moduleOne.example.com** which is separated angular application which use **master** restfulAPI.

It is possible for **moduleOne** to detect that user was logged into **master** and automatically login to restfulAPI as that user using **oauth2** (so user don't need to type credentials twice)? How to do it?

Comment: If you can pass the token, it works. I achieved this before for chrome extension & website. Opened an iframe (with 0 height & width, so invisible) in extension of Laravel blade that gave the `access_token` to the extension

Comment: Let me know if you need an example code

Comment: @senty example code is welcome - especially laravel part (passport/oauth2 configuration and api for link to module and module login) (I assume that user login into master in standard-laravel way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, user was logged-in into my Laravel website and I had to login the same user to the Chrome extension (which is same app's client - auth through passport) with the same user.

First I created a view for the iframe.

```
Route::get('/login-iframe', 'ExtensionAuthController@index');
```

In my method, as I knew logged in user, I passed it to the view as well as newly created `access_token`.

```
public function index() {
    $user = Auth::user();

    if (!$user) {
        return view('iframe')->with(['user' => null]);
    } else {
        $token = $user->createToken('extension')->accessToken;

        return view('iframe')->with([
            'user' => $user,
            'access_token' => $token
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then, in `iframe.blade.php`, it's a simple html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
</html>
<body>
   <script>
       window.onload = function () {
           @if ($user)
               var user = '{!! $user !!}';
               var token = '{{ $access_token }}';
               parent.postMessage({connectStatus:"connected", user:"" + user + "", accessToken:"" + token + ""}, "*");
           @else
               parent.postMessage({connectStatus:"needs-auth"}, "*");
           @endif
       };
   </script>
</body>
```

In above chunk, `parent.postMessage()` allows you to talk with parent.

In my front-end, I used a bit of logic but really simplifying it:

```
let iframeUrl = 'directUrlHere';

let elt = document.createElement('iframe');
elt.id = 'auth_iframe';  // I have a css rules for hiding it
elt.src = iframeUrl;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elt);

let eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
let eventer = window[eventMethod];
let messageEvent = eventMethod === "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.data.connectStatus !== 'connected') {
         // not logged in so show login screen
         return;
    }

    let user = JSON.parse(e.data.user);
    let accessToken = e.data.accessToken;
});
```

Now, using the `accessToken`, you can authenticate to the passport!